# PHP: Parsed PDF-File full of Control-Characters

Tags: php, pdf, control-characters, pdf-parsing

I've got a problem parsing this pdf-file:

http://www.transperfect.com/sites/default/files/imported/pdf/Tokyo_Client_Services_Representative.pdf

After I encoded the FlateDecode decoded pdf-file the output is something like this:

[image]

Usually it's easy to parse the content, because the text content is always inside the opened "(" and closed ")" bracket but this pdf-file is giving me a headache.
It seems like there are just control-characters inside the brackets.

My current output is the following:

[image]

Anyone here who have a clue about this ? What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You are wrong in your assumption text in parentheses is "text content". It *may* look like it but it's not required. Read Chapter 5 of Adobe's PDF Reference 1.7, and in particular **5.5.5 Character Encoding**: "A font’s *encoding* is the association between character codes (obtained from text strings that are shown) and glyph descriptions. [...] A font program’s built-in encoding can be overridden or altered by including an **Encoding** entry in the PDF font dictionary."

Comment: ... properly parsing the character codes per font according to their `/ToUnicode` entries, I get the text "(firm name omitted) provide the highest quality language services to leading businesses worldwide ...", and so on for 30 lines.

Comment: Please spend some hours studying the PDF reference. It's freely available.